# Black window installing Visual Studio 2017

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to install VS2017 on  Windows 10 running on Parallel Desktop for Mac. If I click "Continue" in the below form

[image]

the following back windows appear with:

[image]

I've tried  both offline and online install with no luck. In the same machine I have installed successfully VS2012,VS2013,VS2015 without any problem.

**EDIT:**
**Finally I find a way that work**. I've downloaded the offline installer and I've Launched it in Windows 7 Compatibility mode and "Disable display scaling on hight DPI settings"

[image]

Comment: what steps are you following? it's a bit unclear what `step 2` is...

Comment: coudl you be more specific about what `step 2` is?

Comment: @ Deathstorm I've edited my answer

Comment: @christianmini You need to update your windows, VS17 requirements are not already installed. Do read and install carefully. Try to install as an administrator

Comment: Open up task manager and check available ram at that stage.

Comment: Why you don't want to try [Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have .net framework 4.5? It is required to install VS17. Notice that VS17 supports only Windows 10 version 1507 or higher and doesn't support Enterprise LTSB edition.

Also if running on a virtual machine it requires 2.5GB RAM minimum.